Iterate merge/VLOOKUP over multiple dataframes
I have multiple dataframes that I want to apply the same merge to.
data_1 = [[1, "Sarah"], [2, "Kevin"], [3, "Mark"]]
data_2 = [[1, "Bart"], [5, "Nina"], [4, "John"]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns=["Floor", "Name"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns=["Floor", "Name"])

key = [[1, "Security"], [2, "HR"], [3, "Finance"], [4, "Marketing"], [5, "R&D"]]
key_df = pd.DataFrame(key, columns=["Floor", "Dept"])

I'm wondering if there's a way to use a for loop to create these two final dataframes:
df1
Floor   Name    Dept
0   1   Sarah   Security
1   2   Kevin   HR
2   3   Mark    Finance

df2
Floor   Name    Dept
0   1   Bart    Security
1   5   Nina    R&D
2   4   John    Marketing

The only solution I've found so far is the method below, but each dataframe would need to be extracted from the list afterwards, which seems like more work than doing the merges individually.
all_df = [df1, df2]
all_merge = []

for df in all_df:
    df_merge = df.merge(key_df)
    all_merge.append(df_merge)


You just need to change the merge to:
df_merge = df.merge(key_df,on='Floor')

Check out other ways to merge tables in this image.

please consider add a link to the official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

It looks like you want to update the original DataFrames in place.
You could add the "Dept" column manually in your loop:
dfs = [df1, df2]
dept = key_df.set_index('Floor')['Dept']

for x in dfs:
    x['Dept'] = x['Floor'].map(dept)

If you have more complex operations to perform, then you should rethink your strategy and not rely on variable names. Instead use a dictionary to hold the datasets and chose meaningful names (something like main_building, London_branch…). Then you will be able to maintain a unique object with meaningful tags/keys to retrieve each DataFrame:
dfs = {'London': df1, 'Singapore_South': df2}
out = {k: x.merge(key_df) for k, x in dfs.items()}

out['London']

   Floor   Name      Dept
0      1  Sarah  Security
1      2  Kevin        HR
2      3   Mark   Finance

